# Searching for a specific string in a cell, and then returning only specific values after the string

Tags: python, excel, excel-formula

I have an excel list, and one of the columns has all the information I need. Unfortunately this information needs to be split up into several columns.

Example of how it is right now:

```
article number; description
12345; apple random strings colour red random strings size medium random strings random strings weight 50g 
random strings
```

Example of how it needs to be:

```
article number; description; size; colour; weight
12345; apple; medium; red; 50g
```

I have had limited success with the FIND funciton in Excel. Unfortunately the numeric values do not always have the same length. So sometimes I would get 5 instead of 50 as a result, which would be wrong.

The values of interest are not always in the same order. The goal is to search for several specific strings and return the value after it to a column.

Comment: What rule can you use to know that, in your results, `Description = apple`. Will it always be the third word?  Will it always be the word following the color descriptor? Or do you need to have a list of possible descriptions?

Comment: The word of interest will always follow 'colour' or 'size' for example. It is almost always in the same order.

Comment: But `apple` follows neither. Did you check my power query solution?

Comment: You are correct. I believe there is no pattern for "apple", no exact word always comes before it unfortunately. In most cases the first word of the cell would suffice for the description. Unfortunately I have not had the time to check out your query. I will definitely get to it as soon as I can and give feedback. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a Power Query method that makes the following assumptions:

- The `description` for the output will be the second word after `colour`
- The other descriptors will be followed by a single word with the value of the descriptor
- The descriptors do not have to be in any particular order.
- There is only a single space between words.

To create this:

- Select a cell in your two column data table
- `Data => Get&Transform => From Table/Range`
- In the PQ UI, navigate to `Home => Advanced Editor`
- Make note of the Table name in Line 2
- Paste the M-Code below to replace the existing M-Code
- Examine the inline comments, as well as the Applied Steps panel in PQ to understand what is going on

  - In summary, we

    - create a list of the desired descriptors
    - create another list of the words in `description` column from the source data
    - Finding the position of each descriptor, we return the adjacent word (adjacent second word to find the `description`
    - Combine the results to create our output table.

**M Code**

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table3"]}[Content],

//Valid column headers in desired order
colHdrs = {"colour","size", "weight"},


    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"article number", Int64.Type}, {"description", type text}}),

//Split the description cell into a list by <space>
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "splitDescription", each Text.Split([description]," ")),

//Match each descriptor (colHdrs) with the following word in the split descriptor list
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "Descriptions", each 
        List.Accumulate(colHdrs,

//Note that `Description` is matched with the second word following "colour"
            {[splitDescription]{List.PositionOf([splitDescription], "colour")+2}},
            (state,current)=> 
                if List.PositionOf([splitDescription],current) >= 0
                    then List.Combine({state,{[splitDescription]{List.PositionOf([splitDescription], current)+1}}})
                else List.Combine({state,{null}}))),

//create a column of table records
    #"Added Custom2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom1", "descriptorRecords", each Record.FromList([Descriptions], List.Combine({{"description"},colHdrs}))),

//clean up and expand the Records column into a Table
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom2",{"description", "splitDescription", "Descriptions"}),
    #"Expanded descriptorRecords" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Removed Columns", "descriptorRecords", {"description", "colour", "size", "weight"}, {"description", "colour", "size", "weight"}),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded descriptorRecords",{{"description", type text}, {"colour", type text}, {"size", type text}, {"weight", type text}})
in
    #"Changed Type1"
```

**Source**

[image]

**Results**

[image]

And if your Source data changes, merely Refresh the query.

Comment: I have had a chance to test it. Unfortunately the patterns of my source are just too random too often. Is there a way to match the same way you did for "colour" for several additional descriptors? That way I can find every descriptor, and then return the adjacent word in a separate column.

Comment: @alemaite Yes, of course there is. Line 4 has the list of key words (they become column headers). You'll also need to modify lines further down where they are referenced.

Comment: unfortunately I have found out that the strings of interest are not always in the same order. I have tried (and failed) to adapt your code accordingly and have edited the OP. Maybe you can take a look? : )

Comment: @alemaite Your problem is unclear. The code I provided is not sensitive to the order of the strings of interest. So what, exactly, is the issue?  *Of course, there is no method to determine where `apple` will be located, and you have not bothered to clarify that. From your first example, apple was the second word after the colour descriptor. In your second example, it is the first word in the description string.* Those are the only two examples you have given, but I assume there is more variability. You may need to develop a list of possible types and see which matches.

Comment: @alemaite By possible types, I mean, for example, `apple`, `orange`, `shirt`, etc

Comment: I misunderstood your comment for the headers in the code ("desired order") and probably wasted a lot of time trying to adjust a working code : ). I figured out too late that the code is not sensitive to the order of strings, but then had no time to change it and test it again. Sorry for the confusion, I will edit the OP to not confuse more people and test more on Monday. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @alemaite Yes "desired order" is supposed to mean the order you desire for the output columns.  And, as I wrote, you'll need to figure out about the single word `description` and  how to best identify it.